# Meaning of "Ship in volume"

Tags: meaning, idioms

From the following sentence:

> Weintraub says that the distortions began with Jobs' first bullet points, in which a slide claims that the iPad 2 is the "First dual core tablet **to ship in volume**." Weintraub notes that the Dell Streak 7 has been shipping since January, and the Xoom "is certainly **shipping in volume** as well."

What is the meaning of "ship in volume" and what is the difference from regular shipping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ship*, as verb, means "be made available for purchase," and it is usually used when referring to products.

*Made available in volume* means "made available in large amounts."

Comment: [5. A synonym for quantity. (The volume of ticket sales decreased this week.)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/volume#English)

Comment: @mplungjan What does _large amounts_ mean? Does it mean "in few quantities"?

Comment: @Kiam I only commented to give a link to some kind of dictionary. It was not at all a critique of your answer which I voted up.

Comment: @mplungjan I apologize; I misunderstood what you meant, and over-reacted.

Comment: @Kiam, No problem. I could have been clearer. I did not want to post an answer since it had already been answered

Comment: In this context it means "widely available" - the stores will have enough to put on shelves without limiting the purchases.

Comment: @mplungjan: "in volume" in this context is not about the manner in which it's shipped; "in volume" is about how much shipping the seller is doing. "Shipping in volume" is equivalent to "We are selling lots of these."

Answer (score 1):

According to [TheFreeOnlineDictionary's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/volume) entry:

> **volume** 4b. A large amount. Often used in the plural: *volumes of praise*.

So people use *volume* to mean both capacity and *great* capacity, amount and *great* amount. It's similar to how the word *quality* is used as a neutral descriptor as well as a positive comparator. Consider:

> The company shipped quality goods in large volume.

This means the company shipped a lot of high-quality products.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this means that they ship large quantities of it.

Which in turn means it's **expected to be** popular.

Comment: Meaning it is AVAILABLE and **expected** to be popular - and iPad was but that is not the meaning of the expression

Comment: @mplungjan: True. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

"Ship" is being used in the first meaning listed for it as a verb in [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ship#Verb): to send something to someone or somewhere.  In this particular context it implicitly means shipping from the manufacturer's warehouses to the shops.

"In volume" means "in large amounts"; several other answers have references for this, so I won't poach.

So overall the phrase "ship in volume" means "get into the shops in large amounts."  When a product ships in volume, you will be able to find it in the stores (or at least the stores you would normally expect to find an iPad in!)  The alternatives in business terms would be "ship small volumes", i.e. getting only to relatively small numbers of shops (probably specialists), and "sample" (a few "samples" of the product are available to a few major customers, but it's not available to the rest of us yet).